# Ubuntu 17.10 stuck at grub command prompt

Tags: xubuntu, 17.10

[image]
 Ubuntu 17.10 was working fine. Then I tried to install windows 10 from unebootin but I stuck in state. Windows recovery environment (/dev/sda2).

Ubuntu installed in dev/sda1.
Unable to charge bios to efi and bios locked.

Help me nothing working.

Not able to use sudo command from grub command line.

Regards.
Mukesh

Comment: this is the grub command line, not windows recovery. Was ubuntu installed in EFI mode? Also, Windows 10 installations are known for deleting linux partitions.

Comment: If you mention EFI then it's no BIOS, it's UEFI. UEFI installs are different and if Ubuntu was previously installed in that mode as it should then, assuming the users know what they're doing, installing Windows should not affect Ubuntu and vice versa. And UEFI (the replacement for old BIOS) is not looked either way. The same key can be used to access the firmware settings but must be pressed (spammed) immediately after powering it on.